# App crashes at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My app crashes when I scroll the UITableView over the first cell or the last cell!
Why this is happening? I add with addObject:name the objects of the UItableview . This is the code I use at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Help please! I have been trying to figure out what is going wrong hours!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString * DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier = 
    @"DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: 
                             DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier: DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier]
                autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

 NSString *rowString =nil;

    rowString = [list objectAtIndex:row];

 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    [rowString release];
    return cell;
```

Comment: Please use a <pre></pre> block around your code.

Comment: Please post the code where you allocate the list array and also post the following method - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `[rowString release];` but you never retained it.

Comment: +1 about that release; not only you're never retaining it, if rowString is not nil, you might be releasing an autoreleased object, which is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the problem! God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

Is it throwing an exception - my guess is the index is not set:

```
rowString = [list objectAtIndex:row];
```

Can you set a breakpoint on this line and dump the "list"?